# How to show/hide multiple text inputs in Asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to show/hide multiple text inputs in Asp.net MVC

[I need to show "example" text inputs when "add process" button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTOIi.jpg)

Comment: You need to include the code that you have, also search on "hide input with jquery"

Answer (score 0):

Text input/fields can be hide by giving input type hidden or with applying css with 'display:none'

```
<input type="hidden" id="txtId" name="txt" value="abc">
```

For hiding with css, write inline css with style or make a css class and use in the control as 'class="mycssClass"'